# Trouble booting Windows from GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Lenovo Y700 and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday. I downloaded the iso and installed it in my USB drive using YUMI. I had a problem trying to boot from the USB since it wasn't recognized. I had to go to BIOS and set it to boot from Legacy. Then it already appeared on my boot options.
I installed it, restarted the computer and then GRUB appeared. Everything fine, until I tried to boot Windows. There are two options to boot Windows: Windows 10 and Windows Recovery. None of them worked, it shows a black screen saying I need to recover my Windows. Ubuntu boots fine. 
However, if I switch boot in the BIOS to UEFI, Windows loads just fine (although GRUB isn't displayed).

I have two questions:
Should GRUB be booted with Legacy mode? (I think so but I'm not sure about that)
What can I do to fix my Windows Boot from GRUB?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also, YUMI is obsolete and should not be used on (U)EFI-based computers.

Comment: I fixed it using my USB drive as a UEFI device. Installed it and now it works fine in dual boot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `boot-repair`, it can repair many problems with grub with one click

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have tried that solution but when I run boot-repair it says that my session is in legacy mode.  My USB only boots when I set BIOS to UEFI... Maybe there is something wrong with my USB?